# fmemopen crashes with JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have the following Java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Simple {

    public native void initClient(byte[] buffer, int size);

    static {
            System.loadLibrary("simpleclient");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Simple client = new Simple();
            byte[] buffer = "test".getBytes();

            client.initClient(buffer, buffer.length);
    }

}
```

And the follwing C code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Simple_initClient
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jbyteArray jBuffer, int size)
{

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * size);
    if(buffer == NULL || jBuffer == NULL) return;

    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, jBuffer, 0, size,(jbyte*) buffer );

    FILE * metaFile = NULL;
    metaFile = fmemopen(buffer, size, "rb");
    if(metaFile == NULL) return;

    printf("int _flags %d\n", metaFile->_flags);

}
```

I compile this using:

```
gcc -o libsimpleclient.so -shared -fPIC simpleclient.c

javac Simple.java
java -Djava.library.path=. -cp . Simple
```

This crashes - once in while - with SIGSEGV in the printf call in C.

I ve checked the buffer has valid data for both when it does crash and doesn't crash.

Comment: Try `rb+` or `r+b` instead of `rb` for `fmemopen`

Comment: tried this. still crashes